# Projection performance - performance issue

Tags: mongodb

I have made some performance tests to understand what is the most efficaint way for me to get the data from the following dbobject (see structure bellow)

this is the results I got:
findOne(no projection) - 8 mili seconds

find one(with projection to get only meta field) - 56 mili seconds

findone(with projection to get only description field)- 1 mill seconds

why does it take more time to get the same object with only meta field? I don't understand.
and because I have collection of sessions with index on the _id field, and my query contains the id field, why will projection effact the performance? as its one object, and instead of getting the all object I want to get specific fields.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("605107f63079d85300063b3f"), 
 "description" : "correct", 

"networkPolicy" : {
    "delay" : NumberInt(15), 
    "retries" : NumberInt(8)
}, 
"stopCondition" : "IDLE_DURATION", 
"stopConditionDuration" : NumberInt(30), 
"transformerConfiguration" : {
    "name" : "MULTI AUTO TRANSFORMERCONFIGURATION", 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "description" : "The auto multi transformerconfiguration", 
    "transformerSpecs" : [
        {
            "streamType" : "RWR", 
            "transformerRef" : {
                "name" : "com.aaaa.xplorer.plugin.impl.transformer.rwr.RWRCSVTransformer", 
                "lang" : "JAVA", 
                "version" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "streamName" : "rwr"
        }
    ]
}, 
"filterDelay" : NumberInt(0), 
"viewConfiguration" : {
    "name" : "MULTI AUTO VIEWCONFIGURATION", 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "description" : "The auto multi viewconfiguration", 
    "viewSpecs" : [
        {
            "streamType" : "RWR", 
            "type" : "STRING_TO", 
            "visible" : true, 
            "contextType" : "BASE", 
            "presenter" : {

            }, 
            "seriesSpecs" : [
                {
                    "seriesName" : "fileIndex", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "index", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "dwords", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "episode", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "timestamp", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "source", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "type", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "id", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "name", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "core", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "parameters", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "globalTimestamp", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "linkedIndex", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "processDuration", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "threadId", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "subSource", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "timestamp48", 
                    "visible" : false, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "color" : "N/A", 
                    "hex" : true
                }
            ], 
            "name" : "rwr"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "evaSummary_rwr", 
            "type" : "STRING_TO", 
            "visible" : true, 
            "contextType" : "ANALYSIS", 
            "seriesSpecs" : [
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerName", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerPassCount", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerTotalCount", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerFailCount", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerPassRate", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerSeverity", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerDescription", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "analysisType" : "EVA", 
                    "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerFailRows", 
                    "visible" : true, 
                    "sortable" : false, 
                    "baseFieldTarget" : "index", 
                    "viewFieldSource" : "Fail Row IDs"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, 
"overridden" : false, 
"wizard" : true, 
"collectors" : [
    {
        "type" : "SYSTEM", 
        "name" : "cmd", 
        "version" : NumberInt(1), 
        "content" : "cmd /c"
    }
], 
"analyserConfiguration" : {
    "name" : "MULTI AUTO ANALYSERCONFIGURATION", 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "description" : "The auto multi analyserconfiguration", 
    "analyserSpecs" : [
        {
            "streamType" : "RWR", 
            "analysisType" : "EVA", 
            "streamName" : "rwr", 
            "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
            "analyserRef" : {
                "name" : "com.eva.xplorer.EagleAnalyser", 
                "lang" : "JAVA", 
                "version" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "properties" : [
                {
                    "name" : "project", 
                    "value" : "eagle"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, 
"transformers" : [
    {
        "name" : "com.sandisk.xplorer.plugin.impl.transformer.rwr.RWRCSVTransformer", 
        "lang" : "JAVA", 
        "version" : NumberInt(1), 
        "automaticDependencies" : true, 
        "classpathOverride" : true, 
        "content" : "N/A"
    }
], 
"analysers" : [
    {
        "name" : "com.eva.xplorer.EagleAnalyser", 
        "lang" : "JAVA", 
        "version" : NumberInt(1), 
        "automaticDependencies" : true, 
        "classpathOverride" : true, 
        "options" : [
            {
                "product" : "Sunbird", 
                "projects" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Sunbird", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "sunbird"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Sunbird Samsung", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "sunbird_smsg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "product" : "Eagle", 
                "projects" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Eagle", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "eagle"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Eagle Embedded", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "eagle_emb"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "product" : "Macaw", 
                "projects" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Macaw", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "macaw"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "name" : "runScript", 
                                "value" : "checkers/fa_red_flags_emmc.eva"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Macaw Embedded", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "macaw_emb"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "name" : "runScript", 
                                "value" : "checkers/fa_red_flags_emmc.eva"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "product" : "Swift", 
                "projects" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Swift", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "swift"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "product" : "SwiftPro", 
                "projects" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "SwiftPro", 
                        "properties" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "project", 
                                "value" : "swiftpro"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"storageRef" : {
    "osType" : "WINDOWS", 
    "databaseType" : "MONGO", 
    "version" : "3.6.6", 
    "remoteRef" : {
        "address" : "127.0.0.1", 
        "port" : NumberInt(27017)
    }
}, 
"_instance" : NumberLong(28), 
"_segment" : NumberLong(1), 
"_save" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:33:10.932+0000"), 
"_update" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:34:12.007+0000"), 
"initTimestamp" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:33:13.977+0000"), 
"startTimestamp" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:33:22.913+0000"), 
"meta" : {
    "sessionStatuses" : [
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:34:10.242+0000"), 
            "sessionState" : "TERMINATED", 
            "idleDuration" : NumberLong(26520172900), 
            "bufferStatus" : {
                "capacity" : NumberLong(134217728), 
                "capacityUsed" : NumberLong(0), 
                "capacityMaxUsed" : NumberLong(5566670), 
                "capacityPushed" : NumberLong(6436548), 
                "capacityPulled" : NumberLong(6436548), 
                "elementCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                "elementMaxCount" : NumberLong(1274)
            }, 
            "streamStatuses" : [
                {
                    "name" : "rwr", 
                    "collectorState" : "COMPLETED", 
                    "initErrorCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "executeErrorCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "finalizeErrorCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "terminateErrorCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "pushCount" : NumberLong(1511), 
                    "pullCount" : NumberLong(1511), 
                    "overrideCount" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "capacityUsed" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "capacityMaxUsed" : NumberLong(2738745), 
                    "capacityPushed" : NumberLong(3165389), 
                    "capacityPulled" : NumberLong(3165389), 
                    "capacityOverridden" : NumberLong(0), 
                    "globalStartTimestamp" : ISODate("2021-03-16T19:33:24.172+0000"), 
                    "exitCode" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "state" : "COMPLETED"
                }
            ], 
            "remoteAddress" : "127.0.0.1", 
            "remotePort" : NumberInt(8081)
        }
    ], 
    "sessionTransformers" : [
        {
            "streamName" : "rwr", 
            "failed" : false, 
            "lastInstance" : NumberLong(1511), 
            "state" : {
                "lastElementInstance" : NumberLong(150568), 
                "outputFormat" : "COMPRESSED_STRINGS", 
                "compressType" : "XZ", 
                "fileIndex" : NumberLong(5), 
                "firstLine" : true, 
                "outputFields" : [
                    "index", 
                    "episode", 
                    "timestamp", 
                    "source", 
                    "type", 
                    "subSource", 
                    "threadId", 
                    "id", 
                    "name", 
                    "core", 
                    "parameters", 
                    "fileIndex", 
                    "globalTimestamp", 
                    "linkedIndex", 
                    "processDuration"
                ], 
                "fieldsCount" : NumberInt(15)
            }, 
            "seriesDescriptors" : [
                {
                    "seriesName" : "fileIndex", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "globalTimestamp", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_DATE"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "timestamp", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "index", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "episode", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "source", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "type", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "id", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "name", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "core", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "parameters", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "linkedIndex", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "processDuration", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "threadId", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "subSource", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "dwords", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "timestamp48", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "sessionAnalysers" : [
        {
            "streamName" : "rwr", 
            "analysisName" : "eva_rwr", 
            "lastInstance" : NumberLong(150568), 
            "failed" : false, 
            "state" : {
                "eva" : {
                    "scriptPackageData" : BinData(0, "UEsDBBQAAAAAAAkacFLxjgYRMAEAADAB.. 4461486 more bytes"), 
                    "com_eva_core_ThreadManager0_activeThreadId_s" : NumberInt(2), 
                    "com_eva_core_ThreadManager0_activeThreadName_s" : "INP", 
                    "eva_analysis_done_evaCheckerPassCount" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            }, 
            "seriesDescriptors" : [
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerName", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Checker Name", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerPassCount", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Passed", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerFailCount", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Failed", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerTotalCount", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Total", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerPassRate", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Pass Rate", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerSeverity", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_NUMBER", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Severity", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerDescription", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Description", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaCheckerFailRows", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Fail Row IDs", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPrintText", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "Text", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable0", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val0", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable1", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val1", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable2", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val2", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable3", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val3", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable4", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val4", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable5", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val5", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable6", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val6", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesName" : "evaPlotTable7", 
                    "seriesType" : "STRING_TO_STRING", 
                    "keyName" : "evaCheckSummaryKey", 
                    "valueName" : "val7", 
                    "alwaysNew" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

}

Comment: Maybe the answer is in how you did the performance tests.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe the tests/measurements are flawed and do not represent reality. I too find it hard to believe that a simple projection of a document makes the request take 7x as long, but another projection speeds it up by 8x.